# How can I draw a left pointing triangle using CSS?

Tags: css, css-shapes

It has been a long time since I built this triangle which points up. How can I alter my CSS to point the corner left?

http://jsfiddle.net/3sP8q/

```css
.left-corner {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 15px solid #000;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-corner"></div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how:

```css
.left-corner {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid red;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-corner"></div>
```

Use [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/), it helps a lot!

Comment: That space invader is unreal! :)

Comment: @JamieRead Yeah there are some pretty clever things people can do with one element in CSS! It's been updated since I last checked it with quite a few more (including the space invader), so it's worth checking back to every so often to see what someone has made!

Comment: Perfect solution.  The only change I needed to make in order to keep my triangle the same size is to change the border-top, right and bottom to 15px.  Thank you BeatAlex.

Comment: @Chaddly A yes! Sorry, should have changed the values in the answer. Glad I could help!

Comment: Nice website! I will keep it in favs!